# Heroku Build failed – "Installing node-v6.10.0-linux-x64 ---> Detecting rake tasks sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

PROBLEM: My app works locally but Heroku can't built it

- My App (older version) is already in production and works fine
- After updating my gems Heroku can't build it

LOGFILE:

```
> -----> Ruby app detected
> -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
> -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.4.0
> -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.13.7
>        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
>        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.13.7) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.15.1). We suggest you upgrade
> to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
> [...]
>        Using two_factor_authentication 2.0.0 from https://github.com/Houdini/two_factor_authentication.git (at
> master@20c9d14)
>        Bundle complete! 95 Gemfile dependencies, 166 gems now installed.
>        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
>        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
>        Bundle completed (8.87s)
>        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
>        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.13.7) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.15.1). We suggest you upgrade
> to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
>        Removing rake (11.3.0)
>        Removing sanitize (4.4.0)
>        Removing puma (3.9.0)
> -----> Installing node-v6.10.0-linux-x64
> -----> Detecting rake tasks sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string  !  !     Could
> not detect rake tasks  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake
> -P` against your app  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.  !     rake aborted!  !     LoadError:
> /tmp/build_d57fe8071d52b0e09ad9d1d1102c6aeb/oanstein-oanstein-9fd67121d7068e6188756c5927264e99f0a90d83/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.2/ext/nokogiri/nokogiri.so:
> cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory -
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/nokogumbo-1.4.12/lib/nokogumboc.so
> !    
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'  !    
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'  !    
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'  !    
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'  !    
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/nokogumbo-1.4.12/lib/nokogumbo.rb:2:in
> `<top (required)>'  !    
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'  !    
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'  !    
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'  !    
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'  !    
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sanitize-4.5.0/lib/sanitize.rb:3:in
> `<top (required)>'  !    
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in
> `require'  !    
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in
> `block (2 levels) in require'  !    
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in
> `each'  !    
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in
> `block in require'  !    
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in
> `each'  !    
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in
> `require'  !    
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler.rb:106:in
> `require'  !    
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/config/application.rb:8:in
> `<top (required)>'  !    
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/Rakefile:4:in
> `require_relative'  !    
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/Rakefile:4:in
> `<top (required)>'  !    
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in
> `load'  !    
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in
> `load_rakefile'  !    
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:687:in
> `raw_load_rakefile'  !    
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:96:in
> `block in load_rakefile'  !    
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in
> `standard_exception_handling'  !    
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in
> `load_rakefile'  !    
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in
> `block in run'  !    
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in
> `standard_exception_handling'  !    
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in
> `run'  !    
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in
> `<top (required)>'  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `load'  !    
> vendor/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `<main>'  !
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/helpers/rake_runner.rb:106:in
> `load_rake_tasks!': Could not detect rake tasks
> (LanguagePack::Helpers::RakeRunner::CannotLoadRakefileError) ensure
> you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app and using the
> production group of your Gemfile. rake aborted! LoadError:
> /tmp/build_d57fe8071d52b0e09ad9d1d1102c6aeb/oanstein-oanstein-9fd67121d7068e6188756c5927264e99f0a90d83/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.2/ext/nokogiri/nokogiri.so:
> cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory -
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/nokogumbo-1.4.12/lib/nokogumboc.so
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/nokogumbo-1.4.12/lib/nokogumbo.rb:2:in
> `<top (required)>'
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sanitize-4.5.0/lib/sanitize.rb:3:in
> `<top (required)>'
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in
> `require'
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in
> `block (2 levels) in require'
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in
> `each'
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in
> `block in require'
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in
> `each'
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in
> `require'
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler.rb:106:in
> `require'
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/config/application.rb:8:in
> `<top (required)>'
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/Rakefile:4:in
> `require_relative'
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/Rakefile:4:in
> `<top (required)>'
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in
> `load'
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in
> `load_rakefile'
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:687:in
> `raw_load_rakefile'
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:96:in
> `block in load_rakefile'
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in
> `standard_exception_handling'
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in
> `load_rakefile'
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in
> `block in run'
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in
> `standard_exception_handling'
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in
> `run'
> /tmp/build_29247bb29579dec7ce1e38d2d8a4dac0/oanstein-oanstein-c5fa658ece352b50b13c6f2fe165fd6007dca37a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in
> `<top (required)>' vendor/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `load'
> vendor/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `<main>'     from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:757:in
> `rake'    from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:77:in
> `block (2 levels) in run_assets_precompile_rake_task'     from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:132:in
> `log'     from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:71:in
> `block in run_assets_precompile_rake_task'    from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in
> `block (2 levels) in instrument'  from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in
> `yield_with_block_depth'  from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in
> `block in instrument'     from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/cedar-14/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in
> `realtime'    from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in
> `instrument'  from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:49:in
> `instrument'  from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:45:in
> `instrument'  from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:70:in
> `run_assets_precompile_rake_task'     from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:109:in
> `block (2 levels) in compile'     from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:778:in
> `allow_git'   from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:103:in
> `block in compile'    from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in
> `block (2 levels) in instrument'  from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in
> `yield_with_block_depth'  from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in
> `block in instrument'     from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/cedar-14/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in
> `realtime'    from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in
> `instrument'  from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:49:in
> `instrument'  from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:45:in
> `instrument'  from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:92:in
> `compile'     from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:57:in
> `block in compile'    from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in
> `block (2 levels) in instrument'  from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in
> `yield_with_block_depth'  from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in
> `block in instrument'     from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/cedar-14/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in
> `realtime'    from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in
> `instrument'  from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:49:in
> `instrument'  from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:45:in
> `instrument'  from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:55:in
> `compile'     from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:42:in
> `block in compile'    from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in
> `block (2 levels) in instrument'  from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in
> `yield_with_block_depth'  from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in
> `block in instrument'     from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/cedar-14/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in
> `realtime'    from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in
> `instrument'  from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:49:in
> `instrument'  from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:45:in
> `instrument'  from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:41:in
> `compile'     from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:41:in
> `block in compile'    from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in
> `block (2 levels) in instrument'  from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in
> `yield_with_block_depth'  from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in
> `block in instrument'     from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/cedar-14/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in
> `realtime'    from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in
> `instrument'  from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:49:in
> `instrument'  from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:45:in
> `instrument'  from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:40:in
> `compile'     from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/bin/support/ruby_compile:20:in
> `block (2 levels) in <main>'  from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:132:in
> `log'     from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/bin/support/ruby_compile:19:in
> `block in <main>'     from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in
> `block in trace'  from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in
> `block (2 levels) in instrument'  from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in
> `yield_with_block_depth'  from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in
> `block in instrument'     from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/cedar-14/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in
> `realtime'    from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in
> `instrument'  from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in
> `trace'   from
> /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/bin/support/ruby_compile:15:in
> `<main>'  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.  !     Push
> failed
```

There is this error in the logs:

> load_rake_tasks!': Could not detect rake tasks
>   LanguagePack::Helpers::RakeRunner::CannotLoadRakefileError) ensure you
>   can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app and using the
>   production group of your Gemfile

MY GEM CHANGES
[image]

Comment: My RoR version is 5.1.1

Comment: I downgraded puma to initial version (2.8.2) -> still not able to build on heroku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problematic gem: **Nokogumbo 1.4.12 crashes on Heroku**

https://github.com/rubys/nokogumbo/issues/61

Rolled it back to 1.4.11 and now Heroku is able to build the app